# Registration Form import error

Tags: django

I am following DjangoBook tutorial and i have encountered a problem on chapter 14 ( User Registration )

In *django.contrib.auth.forms* , there is a `UserCreationForm` class. I am trying to create a new class based on `UserCreationForm` called `RegisterForm`

This is my class `RegisterForm` in *django.contrib.auth.forms*

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    fullname = forms.CharField(label="Full name")

    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields = ("username","fullname","email",)
```

This is the view function

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(UserCreationForm)
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {
        'form': form,
    })
```

I have no idea why i am getting a ImportError which states that I cannot import name `RegisterForm` in my view , can someone help me out thanks.

This is my stack trace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'mysite.books')
Installed Middleware:
 ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns",                      self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
35.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\Ray Lim\Desktop\project\home\username\djcode\mysite\mysite\urls.py" in    <module>
14. from mysite.books import views
File "C:\Users\Ray    Lim\Desktop\project\home\username\djcode\mysite\mysite\books\views.py" in <module>
11. from django.contrib.auth.forms import RegisterForm

Exception Type: ImportError at /register/
Exception Value: cannot import name RegisterForm
```

Comment: Have you edited `django.contrib.auth.forms` to add your class? What is complete stack trace?

Comment: I'm confused—UserCreationForm is the parent of the RegisterForm?  Why then you're sending it in the view function as parameter (`form = RegisterForm(UserCreationForm)`)?

Comment: @DenisMalinovsky I am new to Django , how should i call RegisterForm.     Rohan: yea i have added the class to django.contrib.auth.forms

Comment: It's not Django, it's Python thing.  You should just do `form = RegisterForm()`.  Also, to make sure your new form class is really in forms.py, you can do `import django.contrib.auth.forms as form; print dir(form)` to see all the function etc. which forms.py defines.

Comment: why does it work when the class RegisterForm is in the view.py??? Why cant i import it from django.contrib.auth.forms

Comment: Because `django.contrib.auth.forms` no longer has `RegisterForm` in it.

Comment: @IvanKharlamov I added RegisterForm to django.contrib.auth.forms

Comment: You see, you're not supposed to make changes to Django code if you don't understand, what's going on. After you've added `RegisterForm` to `django.contrib.auth.forms` the import error should probably go away, but, chance is, there would be other errors. The best way for you to go is to install version of Django that is used in DjangoBook itself. ... But, what you should do first, is **[read a book about Python](http://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-Absolute-Beginner-3rd/dp/1435455002/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1367740040&sr=1-7&keywords=learning+python)**.

Answer (score 1):

As of **Django 1.5** there is no such form in the module `django.contrib.auth.forms.`

You might want to use an editor that would highlight such things for you. Such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Still, point stands, you should have at least basic understanding of `Python` to learn `Django`. You see, the statements

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm)    
    ...
# And then:
form = RegisterForm(UserCreationForm)
```

Hardly make any sense from Python perspective.

You are writing Python code. In Python. You'll have to learn Python. Yes, it is possible to go another way, but it is much harder.

Comment: i did import the RegisterForm at the start